# How to set API key in Google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I'm working in a `bootstrap` theme and I'm having some trouble adding the `google maps api`. The map is in a `javascript` file and it is like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

function init() {

    var mapOptions = {

        zoom: 15,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.428005, -8.674701),

        styles: [
        {
...

    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.428005, -8.674701),
        map: map,
```

And in html there is only this:

```
    <section class="map">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </section>
```

How can I add the `Api` key here?

Thank you.

Comment: then add this <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR KEY&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>

Comment: I've tried that before and it didnt work. Maybe i'm doing something wrong with the code. Can you please give me an example? I'm sorry, i'm new at this, and thank you.

Comment: yes get a key from google developer console and replace it with YOUR KEY in script tag

Comment: I'm not that "new"... I have put the api key. It still returns the missingkeymap error. Maybe i'm making some mistake in the code.

Answer (score 3):

The key to the Google Maps API is included as a query parameter with the URL when you include the script on your site.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
```